# How can I configure exim4 to route mail like this?

Tags: email, exim

I have exim4 installed on a debian wheezy box and configuring it seems difficult.

I have a dynamic list of usernames (A user named `$USER` exists iff the directory `/.../us/$USER` exists).

When exim receives an email for `user@example.com`, I want it to

- Fail if `user` is not in that list
- Pipe the email to a script otherwise

How can I configure exim4 to do this?

Note: The format of the username list is not that important since I control the user-adding code and therefore I can change it to something more exim-friendly